# Solving Lotka-Volterra model using Euler's method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am trying to solve Lotka-Volterra prey and predator model using Euler's method.

> Let $p$ be the prey density and $q$ is the predator density, thus: $$\frac{dp}{dt} = ap\left(1-\frac{p}{K}\right)-\frac{bpq}{1+bp}$$ $$\frac{dq}{dt}=mq\left(1-\frac{q}{kp}\right).$$

Where $bpq$ is the interaction rate between the species, $\frac{bpq}{1+bp}$ is the effective rate of eating prey, $m$ is the mortality rate of the predators, $K$ and $k$ are the carrying capacitance of each population. Let $a=0.2, \ m=0.1, \ K=500,\ k = 0.2.$

I know that for Euler's method, $$p_i = p_{i-1}+\text{p-slope}_{i-1}\Delta t$$ $$q_i = q_{i-1}+\text{q-slope}_{i-1}\Delta t.$$ Thus, $$p_i = p_{i-1}+\left(ap_{i-1}-bx_{i-1}q_{i-1}\right)\Delta t$$ and similarly for $q_i$, but I am not sure how to set it up properly so that I am able to compute Euler's method.

Comment: @Amzoti $h$ and initial point is up to us, but we can let $b = 0.1$ and $p$ can be around $10$ and $q$ around $5$.

Comment: 1. It seems odd to call k the carrying capacity of the q-population. 2. Would you have a source for this *Lotka-Volterra like* model with some -q/(kp) term?

Comment: @Did How come for your first question? For your second question, I do not have the source.

Comment: Who suggested that you study this model? // The carrying capacity of a population is often defined as its limit when it evolves in isolation. For example, the parameter K is the carrying capacity of the p-population because, when there is no q-population (q=0) or, equivalently, when one suppresses the interaction term (b=0), the p-population converges to K. Is there a similar interpretation of k as describing the behaviour of the q-population? Not in the absence of the p-population, obviously, but...

Comment: @Did Hm I am not sure. The professor wanted us to vary $b$ in some defined integral and see what happens then.

Comment: Are you trying to answer me? Surely I am slow but I see no relation between your last comment and mine.

Comment: @Did I am slow. But I will email my professor stating what you said and I will reply back once he responds.

Comment: Any news from your professor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are given:

> Let $p$ be the prey density and $q$ is the predator density, thus: $$\frac{dp}{dt} = ap\left(1-\frac{p}{K}\right)-\frac{bpq}{1+bp}$$ $$\frac{dq}{dt}=mq\left(1-\frac{q}{kp}\right).$$

We are also given $a=0.2, \ m=0.1, \ K=500,\ k = 0.2, b = 0.1, p(0) = 10, q(0) = 5.$ We will choose $\Delta t = h = 0.1$.

You provided the important piece of information:

$$p_i = p_{i-1}+\text{p-slope}_{i-1}\Delta t$$

$$q_i = q_{i-1}+\text{q-slope}_{i-1}\Delta t.$$

This leads to the recurrence:

$$\begin{align} p_i& = p_{i-1} + \left(0.2~ p_{i-1}\left(1 - \dfrac{p_{i-1}}{500}\right) -\dfrac{0.1~ p_{i-1}~ q_{i-1}}{1 + 0.1~ p_{i-1}} \right)(0.1) \\ q_i& = q_{i-1} + \left(0.1~q_{i-1}\left(1 - \dfrac{q_{i-1}}{0.2~ p_{i-1}}\right) \right)(0.1) \end{align}$$

This gives the iteration:

- $p_0 = 10, q_0 = 5$
- $p_1 = 9.946, q_1 = 4.925$
- $p_2 = 9.89538, q_2 = 4.85231$
- $p_3 = 9.84803, q_3 = 4.78187$
- $\ldots$

Comment: Oh, I see. I was having trouble setting it up but I see what I did wrong now. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are quite welcome and I am not sure why someone downvoted as you clearly tried understanding.

Comment: Amzoti, I noticed around $i=25$ that it starts to diverge. What $dt$ do I need to use in order for it to converge?

Comment: @Luffy: It is possible that it does not provide good enough accuracy and you have to use something like a 4th order Runge-Kutta solution. However, as a first attempt, try making $h = 0.01$ and seeing if that provides enough accuracy and if that fails, try $h = 0.001$. If that fails, you made need a fourth order method like RK4.

Comment: I see. I will try that then. Thanks!