# Using Euler's method to numerically solve the Lotka-Volterra model

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I've been trying to derive the values in the table on pg. 6 from equation (9) on pg. 8 of a paper entitled [Approximate Analytic Solution to the Lotka-Volterra Predator-Prey Differential Equations Model](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/338934386_Approximate_Analytic_Solution_to_the_Lotka_-Volterra_Predator_-Prey_Differential_Equations_Model) by Dionisel Regalado, but stuck in how this was done.

> **Example:** Wolf ate 100 rabbit out of 100 in 2 days. Then, let $a=1, \gamma=0.5, K=500, k=0.82, \beta=1,x_1(0)=100, x_2(0)=100$.
>
> Euler's recursive relation is
>
> $$x_{1_i}=x_{1_{i-1}}+x_{1_{i-1}}\text{slope}_{i-1}\Delta_t$$
> $$x_{2_i}=x_{2_{i-1}}+x_{2_{i-1}}\text{slope}_{i-1}\Delta_t$$
>
> This leads to the recurrence:
>
> $$x_{1_i}=x_{1_{i-1}}+\left(x_{1_{i-1}}\left(1-\frac{x_{1_{i-1}}}{500}\right)-\frac{x_{1_{i-1}}x_{2_{i-1}}}{1+x_{1_{i-1}}}\right)(0.1)$$
> $$x_{2_i}=x_{2_{i-1}}+\left(0.5x_{2_{i-1}}\left(1-\frac{x_{2_{i-1}}}{0.82x_{1_{i-1}}}\right)\right)(0.1)$$
>
> Application of the symbolic regression approach:
>
> $$\begin{array}{|lll|lll|lll|} \hline
> h=0.1&&&h=0.01&&&h=0.001\\ \hline
> t&x_1&x_2&t_{0.01}&x_1&x_2&t&x_1&x_2\\ \hline
> 0&100&100&0&100&100&0&100&100\\
> 0.1&98.09901&98.90244&0.01&99.8099&99.89024&0.001&99.98099&99.98902\\
> 0.2&96.19379&97.76753&0.02&99.61977&99.78012&0.002&99.96198&99.97805\\
> 0.3&99.28635&96.59696&0.03&99.4296&99.66962&0.003&99.94297&99.96706\\
> 0.4&92.37868&95.39239&0.04&99.2394&99.55876&0.004&99.92396&99.95608\\
> 0.5&90.47271&94.15565&0.05&99.04917&99.44754&0.005&99.90495&99.94509\\
> 0.6&88.57028&92.88852&0.06&98.85891&99.33595&0.006&99.88594&99.93409\\
> 0.7&86.67323&91.59287&0.07&98.6682&99.224&0.007&99.86692&99.92309\\
> 0.8&84.78328&90.27057&0.07&98.47831&99.11169&0.008&99.84791&99.91209\\
> 0.9&82.90214&88.92355&0.09&98.28798&98.99902&0.009&98.8289&99.90109\\
> 1&81.03143&87.55375&0.1&98.09763&98.886&0.01&99.80989&99.89008\\ \hline
> \end{array}$$

### My Attempt

$$99+\left(1\cdot99\left(1-\frac{99}{500}\right)-\frac{1\cdot99\cdot99}{1+1\cdot99}\right)\left(0.1\right)\approx 97.1388$$

$$99+\left(0.5\cdot99\left(1-\frac{99}{0.82\cdot99}\right)\right)\left(0.1\right)\approx 97.913$$

However, this is incorrect. I've noted [this superb answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1190360/794754) to a similar question, but was lost in the derivation part. Any hints on where I went wrong?

Also, how would I be able to code this?

Comment: Where does the number $99$ in your calculation come from, are you trying to compute some variation of the table?

Comment: Apologies, but I believe that I erroneously used $x_{1_{i-1}}$ where $x_1(0)=100$, so I had computed $100-1=99$ which I can see now is nonsense. I'd like to compute $t=0.1$ values for $x_1$ and $x_2$ on the table. I've attempted to use the method [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1190360/794754)to find the $p_1 = 9.946, q_1 = 4.925$  values, and then apply this method to this problem.

Comment: Then just applying the formulas should work. What tool do you use for calculation, pocket calculator, spreadsheet or some scripting or programming language? Computers are good at mass production of numbers for the same formula. // I think the intention in the article for the indices was $x_{1,i-1}$, `$x_{1,i-1}$`, no sub-indices. It is not that rare that index manipulations spill over into the actual formula during transcription and produce head-scratchers.

Comment: Many thanks! I use python to run a range of numbers through a function.  I would use this code [found here](https://www.online-python.com/6cDALUFC4r) but don't believe I've used the function properly for this. Would you be able to provide a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paper is rubbish. The system has a limit cycle and of course one can do a harmonic analysis of it.

But applying a purely trigonometric expansion in the initial transient phase will not give useful results. As one can see in the plots, there is a marked evolution in the amplitude. That this is not reflected in the regression model leads to compensation in other places, here the frequencies.

The fitted functions are good for interpolation, this is generally true for regression, but fail at extrapolation, which can be easily checked here as generation of additional data is trivial.

This looks suspiciously like "Here is a tool I do not understand, and I feed it data that I barely understand how to generate and I call the output 'result', make of it what you want".

---

What does it mean "Wolf ate 100 rabbit out of 100 in 2 days"? There is one wolf and 100 rabbits and after 2 days there is one wolf and zero rabbits? Where is that reflected in the model or computation?

---